# SPSS date format when imported into R

Tags: r, time, spss

I have not worked with SPSS (`.sav`) files before and am trying to work with some data files provided to me by importing them into R. I did not receive any explanation of the files, and because communication is difficult I am trying to figure out as much as I can on my own.

Here's my first question. This is what the `Date` field looks like in an R data frame after import:

```
> dataset2$Date[1:4]
[1] 13608172800 13608259200 13608345600 13608345600
```

I don't know what dates the data is supposed to be for, but I found that if I divide the above numbers by 10, that seems to give a reasonable date (in February 2013). **Can anyone confirm this is indeed what the above represents?**

My second question is regarding another column called `Begin_time`. Here's what that looks like:

```
> dataset2$Begin_time[1:4]
[1] 29520 61800 21480 55080
```

Any idea what this is representing? I want to believe this is some representation of time of day because the records are for wildlife observations, but I haven't got more info than that to try to guess. I noticed that if I take the difference between `End_Time` and `Begin_time` I get numbers like 120 and 180, which seems like minutes to me (3 hours seems reasonable to observe a wild animal), but the absolute numbers are far greater than the number of minutes in a day (1440), so that leaves me puzzled. **Is this some time keeping format from SPSS? If so, what's the logic?**

Unfortunately, I don't have access to SPSS, so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Not an SPSS user myself, but maybe `spss.get` from package `Hmisc` helps?

Comment: @beetroot I did not know about that package. Thanks! Yes it would definitely be useful to see if I get more inuitive output loading with another package. The load above did give me a few warnings, although I couldn't decipher which warnings went with whcih columns.

Comment: You may check the package [haven](https://github.com/hadley/haven). From [the first release notes](https://blog.rstudio.org/2015/03/04/haven-0-1-0/): "Dates are converted in to `Date`s, and datetimes to `POSIXct`s.". See also the ["Dates and times" vignette of the package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/haven/vignettes/datetimes.html), which describes the formats of SPSS; "Dates and date times use a difference offset to R"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dates in SPSS Statistics are represented as floating point doubles holding the number of seconds since Oct 1, 1582.  If you use the SPSS R plugin apis, they can be automatically converted to R dates, but any proper converter should be able to do this for you.

Comment: Good answer, however, small correction needed: 1582/10/14 not 1582/10/01!

Answer (score 14):

I had the same problem and this function is a good solution:

```
pss2date <- function(x) as.Date(x/86400, origin = "1582-10-14")
```

This is where I found the answer:

> http://scs.math.yorku.ca/index.php/R:_Importing_dates_from_SPSS

Comment: Explanation: x/86400 gives the number of days (there are 60*60*24 = 86400 second in a day) since October 14th 1582 (which is the starting day of the Gregorian calender)

Comment: Note that all dates in SPSS Statistics are actually datetimes, so there may be a part representing the time.  For date-only values, the time part would be zero.

Comment: Original link is dead. Archived site: http://web.archive.org/web/20190911133029/http://scs.math.yorku.ca/index.php/R:_Importing_dates_from_SPSS